# How do I duplicate a folder and remove dotfiles and PSDs in the duplicate folder?

Tags: bash

I'm a command line noob, so I've got no starting point code, but I know where I want to end up. I would like to take the current working directory and duplicate it in its parent directory (renaming it, of course), then take the copy and find all dotfiles, psds and zip files and get rid of them. Finally I want to zip the duplicate folder up. How would I do that? I know how to do each of those steps via command line as individual steps, but not as one script.

Comment: This is no site to fulfill your programming tasks. Please show the code you already have to get suggestions on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know how to do each of those steps via command line as individual
>   steps, but not as one script.

you just put them together, or join them with `&&` 
for example,

```
parent/working
```

you are under parent, you could

```
    cp -r working bak \
&& find bak/ -name ".*" -o -name "*.psd" -o -name "*.zip"|xargs rm \
&& tar czf working.tar.gz bak \
&& rm -r bak
```

the above just "translated" your question into an answer.

in fact there is simpler way:

you could `tar` your working directory with `--exclude=PATTERN` then you saved `cp, find/remove, and rm -r bak` steps.

Comment: That's cool, and it helps, but is there a way to make that more abstract, so that I could put it in an alias or something and have it work anywhere?

Comment: yes, see the bottom of my answer, you could tar with --exclude, (read man page), it is just one-liner. you could pass in directory as argument, then you got the tarball with those excluded file removed.